# Can't load vector font in Nuclex Framework

Tags: xna, c#, fonts

I've been trying to get this to work for the last 2 hours and I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong...

I've added `Nuclex.TrueTypeImporter` to my references in my content and I've added `Nuclex.Fonts` & `Nuclex.Graphics` in my main project.

I've put `Arial-24-Vector.spritefon`t & `Lindsey.spritefont` in the root of my content directory.

```
_spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Lindsey"); // works

_testFont = Content.Load<VectorFont>("Arial-24-Vector"); // crashes
```

I get this error on the _testFont line:

File contains `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont` but trying to load as `Nuclex.Fonts.VectorFont`.

So I've searched around and by the looks of it it has something to do with the content importer & the content processor. For the content importer I have no new choices, so I leave it as it is, `Sprite Font Description - XNA Framework` for content processor and I select `Vector Font - Nuclex Framework` And then I try to run it.

```
_testFont = Content.Load<VectorFont>("Arial-24-Vector"); // crashes again
```

I get the following error

```
Error loading "Arial-24-Vector".
```

It does work if I load a sprite, so it's not a pathing problem. I've checked the samples, they do work, but I think they also use a different version of the XNA framework because in my version the "Content" class starts with a capital letter.

I'm at a loss, so I ask here.

**Edit:**

Something super weird is going on. I've just added the following two lines to a method inside `FreeTypeFontProcessor::FreeTypeFontProcessor(
    Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Content::Pipeline::Graphics::FontDescription ^fontDescription,
    FontHinter hinter`, just to check if code would even get there:

```
System::Console::WriteLine("I AM HEEREEE");
System::Console::ReadLine();
```

So, I compile it, put it in my project, I run it and... it works! What the hell?? This is weird because I've downloaded the binaries, they didn't work, I've compiled the binaries myself. didn't work either, but now I make a small change to the code and it works? >**_**>.

So, now I remove the two lines, compile it again and it works again. Someone care to elaborate what is going on? Probably some weird caching problem!

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild or did you just do an incremental build?

Comment: @RoyT. Yep, also posted on the nuclex forums: http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/discussions/394286
But I guess this is one of those errors that you fix without knowing what you did and never get again. (I hate those)

Comment: This appears to require a close because the issue was unrelated to the framework and instead user error as indicated by the comments link. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same error as you. It was fixed when I cleaned solution and build it again as @Roy T. suggested.

I think that for some reason Content doesn't rebuild correctly without a clean first.